# How to Remove item from List in Robot framework?

Tags: python, robotframework

Currently we want to remove a specific character from a list in Robot framework. Not able to remove it. Currently regex method string data but not for list data.

```
*** settings ***
Library    Collections

*** Test Cases ***
 Getting a valid response
 [Documentation] Sample List
 @{list} = Create List      a    b   c b c c 
 Log to console ${list}
```

In this sample example it creates a list in format ['a','b','c','b','c','c']. Our realtime data is in JSON format which we have converted into a list. However it creates a format list [{'a','b','c'}]. We want to remove curly braces from our list **{ }**. We tried to use Remove item from list it doesn't work currently. Can someone please help?

Comment: Can you add an [mcve] of how you create the list itself? Without this step reproducing your problem will be somewhat difficult. Perhaps someone has come across this problem before, but if not then this is the only way to help you. In Robot Framework it is possible to work with JSON as this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47523429/6152737) explains in an example.

Comment: There's hardly a single line of code in your example that works. This test will not run as written. If you fix all the syntax errors, this will create a list with three elements: `['a', 'b', 'c b c c']`. Please provide a [mcve] that a) runs, and b) accurately represents the data you are working with.

Comment: What is the type of your data - is it a string, or is it a parsed json (actual `list`, that has members, etc)

Answer (score 0):

1. suppose your json data is in ${json} variable

   `${json}=    Set Variable    [{'a','b','c'}]`
2. now remove unwanted data from string

   `${StringData}=   Remove String   ${json}     {       }   '   ,`
3. Convert string to List using `Convert To List`  keyword

   `@{List}=      Convert To List         ${StringData}`

note: if your json data contains string values like `[{ "Ford", "BMW", "Fiat" }]` then use `Split String` keyword which returns by default list otherwise it will end up in single characters list for more reference look at this [docs](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/String.html#Split%20String)

Comment: this will fail if any of the values in the json data has curly braces in it (eg: [{'a', 'b', '}', 'd'}]`